# Swift Multiple buttons sending String through same segue

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue

Looking for some clarification and just to double check if I am on the right path. I have a category list where multiple buttons will send a specific string through a segue. I have the IBOutlets for each button but want to make sure when that specific button is touched that specific string is sent. I am just unsure if the way I am setting up the segue is correct so that each button is specific to the set strings. So far, the current segue works for "attractionsButton" but when I tap other buttons it passes the same data. I know it's not set, but want to make sure that when another button is tapped its not sending the wrong string.

```
@IBOutlet weak var attractionsButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var eatingButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var financialButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var lodgingButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var medicalButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var publicButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var servicesButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var storesButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var transportationButton: UIButton!

let attractions = "Attractions & Entertainment"
let eating = "Eating & Drinking"
var financial = "Financial Institution"
var lodging = "Lodging Establishment"
var medical = "Medical & Health"
var publicService = "Public Services & Buildings"
var services = "Service"
var stores = "Stores & Shopping"
var transportation = "Transportation"


@IBAction func attractionsButton(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "category", sender: self)
}
@IBAction func eatingButton(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "category", sender: self)
}
@IBAction func financialButton(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "category", sender: self)
}
@IBAction func lodgingButton(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "category", sender: self)
}
@IBAction func medicalButton(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "category", sender: self)
}
@IBAction func publicButton(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "category", sender: self)
}
@IBAction func serviceButton(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "category", sender: self)
}
@IBAction func storesButton(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "category", sender: self)
}
@IBAction func transportationButton(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "category", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
    if segue.identifier == "category" {
        if let button1 = attractionsButton {
            let user = attractions
            let controller = segue.destination as? CategoryListedViewController
            controller?.categoryList = user
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you add the `segue`s? By control-clicking from buttons to other controllers? Or from controller to controller? It should be done by the former way. And more importantly, each segue needs different identifier than others.

Comment: you want to send different string on different button action right. but in every button action, you are set to same string.

Comment: I didn't go from button -> controller, I did controller -> controller.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. If all the buttons do the same thing, why are there multiple IBAction functions? To put it another way: where is you code that check what button was tapped? I don't see any such code.

Comment: I want to set each button like button1, button2, button3, etc. like how I am setting it in "func prepare". Is there a way to set each button to say "hey when this button is tapped send this, when this one is tapped send that" if this is making sense

Comment: Yes there is, but you are not doing that.

Comment: I've checked other questions regarding multiple buttons sending data through the same segue but no one gave a code example of how to set it up

Comment: I did my best by guessing then I came here to get help

Comment: Use the `sender` parameter in `performSegue` - it can be anything you want.

Comment: oh, just switch from "self" to say "attractionsButton"?

Comment: Even simpler. Just switch from `self` to `sender`.

Comment: I find it ridiculous how on StackOverFlow and code helping website, a learning tool, where coders get upset when someone doesn't understand instantly and easily. Are you here to help people learn to code better? or get by with the least amount of help to gain points?

Comment: No idea why matt deleted his answer? Too many comments? Sorry I am not the smartest and just understand information like a plug from the matrix. He has a lot of points and says he's a writer, I am just guessing but shouldn't a writer want to explain thoroughly? Even just for writing practice? *shoulder shrug*

Comment: Im sorry but I see this a lot with this community. A helping website where I feel like Im bothering people for help.

Comment: You can skip using the `@IBAction` altogether and just wire the buttons directly to the next VC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change self in your action to sender, you can use this one action for all the buttons

```
@IBAction func transportationButton(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "category", sender: sender)
}
```

use this code in your prepare for segue

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
    if segue.identifier == "category" {

        let senderButton = sender as! UIButton

        switch senderButton{
        case attractionsButton:
            let user = attractions
            let controller = segue.destination as? CategoryListedViewController
            controller?.categoryList = user
        case eatingButton:
            //editing button scenario
            print("editing button scenario")
        default:
            //default code
            print("default scenario")
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you. Just ran it and it works. I don't know why someone could have just said to use a switch statement for my UIButton outlets under my "func prepare"? That's what I was confused on

Answer (score 1):

All of your buttons can connect to just this one `@IBAction`:

```
@IBAction func allButtons (_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "category", sender: sender)
}
```

Of course, if that is all the buttons are doing, you can skip using the `@IBAction` entirely and just wire the segues from the buttons directly. If you do that when creating the first button in the Storyboard, you can copy that button and all copies will be wired to the same segue.

Then in `prepare(for:sender:)`, compare the sender to your `@IBOutlet`s to set your string:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let button = sender as? UIButton,
       let controller = segue.destination as? CategoryListedViewController,
       segue.identifier == "category" {

        let str: String

        switch button {
        case attractionsButton: str = attractions
        case eatingButton:      str = eating
        case financialButton:   str = financial
        default: str = ""
        }

        controller.categoryList = str
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would use buttons tags and a good old enum to work this out:

First, in Interface Builder, you set the `tag` property of each of your buttons (and you don't even need to have them anymore as `@IBOutlet`)

1 for attractionsButton, 2 for eatingButton, etc.

Then, you create an enum, with raw value as `Int` with matching values :

```
enum Category : Int, CustomStringConvertible {
    case attractions = 1
    case eating = 2
    case financial = 3
    case lodging = 4
    case medical = 5
    case publicService = 6
    case services = 7
    case stores = 8
    case transportation = 9

    var description : String {
        switch self {
        case .attractions: return "Attractions & Entertainment"
        case .eating: return "Eating & Drinking"
        case .financial: return "Financial Institution"
        case .lodging: return "Lodging Establishment"
        case .medical: return "Medical & Health"
        case .publicService: return "Public Services & Buildings"
        case .services: return "Service"
        case .stores: return "Stores & Shopping"
        case .transportation: return "Transportation"
        }
    }
}
```

After that, you link all your buttons to only one `@IBAction` like this one:

```
@IBAction func onButtonTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "category", sender: Category(rawValue: sender.tag))
}
```

This way, according to the tag of the button, you'll create the enum you need.

As an end, in your segue preparation, you can set things like that:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "category" {
        guard
            let controller = segue.destination as? CategoryListedViewController,
            let category = sender as? Category
            else { return }

        controller.categoryList = category.description
    }
}
```

This way, things are much more concise and you can attache more behaviors to your enum `Category`, use it in switches, and so on, instead of relying on `Strings` or multiplying copy&paste code.